# How do I properly bridge asp mvc 3 and a mongodb database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm a beginner trying to teach myself web development from scratch so I can build the serious social network startup I see in my mind. I've chosen to work with asp.net MVC3 in C# with mongodb. Now, I've learned a lot of info on MVC and on Mongodb but I am still unclear on how they should interact in a semipro setting. Obviously, there's plenty of stuff on how MVC works with sql, but I can't find a lot about mongodb with asp MVC. I know the newest official C# driver supports LINQ and I read about all these things like the repository pattern/entity framework/NoRM/NHibernate and I see stuff like http://mongorepository.codeplex.com/.

Which of these things do I need to learn to use aspmvc and mongo together in a semi professional enterprise kinda way? All this info overload is just making my head spin. I can't seem to find a clear answer, if there is one. I prefer to do things the proper way, as much as a beginner can, and I could use a little guidance in this area because I want this to be at least halfway professional. These are probably preschool questions to you guys but do I just use LINQ to get stuff(profiles/blog posts) in and out of the mongo database? Do I use LINQ AND repository pattern? Does Entity fit in there anywhere? Is there something else I should be using entirely? I guess what I am asking is by what methods/patterns/frameworks should I use to persist these domain model objects into my mongodb? (I hope I used some of that jargon right haha. Its very late!) I'm dying to learn but I just need to know what to learn. Any advice or tips you talented folk can offer would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance for reading this far into my ramblings.

Comment: These are all great questions Wesley.  I think the proper answer for most of them is "it depends".  On what basis did you choose MongoDB?  Is your data non-relational or will it be denormalized?  If so, then that is a great fit.  You've also chosen MVC, but for what reasons?  Answers to most of your questions are going to come down to what your business needs are and you haven't provided those.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Craig. I got a couple mongo books and I liked how fast, simple, schemaless,and amazingly scalable it seemed. Also, the built in geospatial features. I chose MVC because, from what I've been reading, people say that MVC is the way you should go to build a serious webapp. Business needs- I need to store and retrieve user profile information, blog posts, comments, classifieds, search tags,user authentications/roles, search for people/posts. Basically a lot of the standard business needs most social sites like twitter or craigslist have. Hope that answered your Q's. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answers.  Now, I guess my question is, what are your specific questions?  There are a gillion ways to build websites using MVC and MongoDB and your question is kind of general.  Should you use the repository pattern - perhaps, there is nothing wrong with it, but that doesn't mean you should use it, and it also doesn't mean you shouldn't.

Comment: Sorry for the super general questions. I guess I don't know enough yet to know what to ask exactly haha. Thanks for your patience. Specifically, I'd just like to know/understand what some of the more popular options are for doing this kinda of thing with mongo. The pros and cons. I'm looking for whats not too difficult to learn but will get the job done. I would like to know how I should get my data from the model business logic to the database. Am I right in assuming there should be some sort of intermediary layer that goes between the business code in the model and the database itself?

Answer (score 0):

RE: Comment #4...

That is a great question.  No, that's not a bad assumption, but it is one that is highly debated and the answer again, it depends.  http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/do-we-need-the-repository-pattern is a good discussion on the subject.  While it doesn't talk specifically about mongodb it speaks specifically towards your abstraction question.

In regards to MongoDB specifically, it is quite simple to get data in and out.  You can read the quickstart here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Quickstart.  As to whether or not you create your intermediary layer is up to you.  It depends on the complexity of your application, how big it will be, if you think you might changed data layers at some point, etc...